# Registration form save

Tags: django

I try to save two forms in registration. I can see the auth form save but the second form is not pass .is_valid(). Could you please let me know what is wrong?

Models.py

```
class School(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    Domain = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    Mascot = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='mascot')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Mascot.delete()
        super(School, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class HeepooUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    allow_phone = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    school_id = models.IntegerField()
    date_join = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')


class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    school_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=School.objects.all())
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=15, min_length=10, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = HeepooUser
        fields = ('phone', 'school_id')
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user = user_form.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile = profile_form.save()

            registered = True
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Wrong access1')
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = RegisterForm()

    return render(request, "register.html", {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
        'registered': registered,
    })
```

I try to save email and password to auth_user and school_id and phone to separate table.

All the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested your code and what I've encountered when submitting a form is

```
school_id value must be an integer
```

I'm suggesting to set school_id/school to be a foreignKey of the School model

```
class HeepooUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    allow_phone = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    school_id = models.ForeignKey(School)
    date_join = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

so that we could just do the forms like this

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HeepooUser
        exclude = ('allow_phone', 'user')
```

also I think you don't need to specify the form fields for UserForm since by default django user only requires a password, username, and email

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how binary ANDs work. If user_form.is_valid() returns False, the "if" statement marks the whole statement as False without needing to evaluate profile_form.is_valid().  Therefore, profile_form.is_valid() never gets called and it's errors dict will not get populated. Unfortunately, django's form is_valid() does more than just return a boolean and has the side effect of populating that errors dict.

```
if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
    ...
```

One thing you might be able to do is something like this:

```
user_valid = False
if user_form.is_valid():
   user_valid = True

profile_valid = False
if profile_form.is_valid():
   profile_valid = True

if user_valid and profile_valid:
   ... do something
```

The above ensures that both forms get processed.  There might be a better way to express it, but that's the idea.